# media player still plays in all activities when device is rotated even though locked to portrait

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

This is my first time dealing with media player, i have a sound play when the app starts but the problem i am having is a sound is played again when device is rotated even though it is locked to portrait, this is happening in all the fragments when rotated and i only want the sound to play when the app starts and not again!
i have tried adding..

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

to the manifest in mainactivity as advised by someone but this is not working and seems odd to me!

here is my main activity java code with the media player set up.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"Welcome");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopThreeFragment(),"Main Display");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopPaidFragment(),"Options");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ForthTestFragment(),"news");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new About(),"About");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.firsteps);
        mp.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this one

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

to

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` 
this one.

And Make by double check you are adding this to related activtiy.

Comment: just realised i cant add this to each one in manifest because its 5 fragments that cause the problem

Comment: i have tested app again and can confirmit is the 5 fragments that although i have them programiticly locked to portrait, the sound from the main activity still plays when device is rotated on the fragments

Comment: add this property only to activity which create fragments.

Comment: It works, i added to the main activity tab in manifest and it seems to work! although the first fragment rotates on first view even though i have set it to portrait by overiding setUserVisibleHint

Comment: @DavidMarsh great if help you any way please consider tick mark and vote up please.